# Android YUV_420_888 outputs gray U and V channels (should be color)

Tags: android, android-camera2

I'm using Android's Camera2 interface, and reading ImageFormat.YUV_420_888 into an ImageReader.

Everything appears to work, except that my U and V channels are extremely gray (i.e. almost all values are very close to 127).

The Y channel looks perfect.

In the same capture session I also send preview images to a TextureView for live preview, and the colors there are clearly correct. So it's only when sending this same stream to my ImageReader in YUV_420_888, that my U and V are incorrect.

Has anybody seen this before?

Phone: Xiaomi Redmi Note 9 Pro
OS: Android 11 RKQ1.200826.002, Kernel 4.14.180-perf-g3a35bde

Comment: Are you converting the YUV output to Bitmap?

Comment: I'm using turbojpeg to save the YUV planes to an image - that's how I see the output. But if I inspect the memory in the debugger, I can see that almost all UV values are close to 0x80

Comment: @BenHarper are you able to fix this ? 
I am still getting this issue on Samsung S21 & S22

Comment: @PrinceAli I don't think I ever solved this, but I ended up just drawing each frame to the screen manually, which was fast enough for my needs.